# Registering a service-worker in Mozilla Thimble

Tags: javascript, android, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is [Mozilla Thimble](https://thimble.mozilla.org) explicitly doing something to prevent service-workers from loading?

I am preparing a tutorial for teenagers on how to create a web game and install it on their smartphone. I am getting them to use [Mozilla Thimble](https://thimble.mozilla.org) so that they can see the results of their changes immediately.

In order to trigger the web app installation banner on Android, the game needs to register a service worker. However, I am getting the following error in Google Chrome.

```
ServiceWorker registration failed:
TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

The `service-worker.js` is registered inside a `main.js` script. I have checked that the URL provided in the `main.js` script is correct. I have loaded the `service-worker.js` script directly through the `index.html` page, to ensure that it loads. I have checked within the `service-worker.js` script that its URL is exactly the same as what `main.js` is asking for. Mozilla Thimble is delivered over the "https://" protocol.

In Firefox, the error is different:

```
ServiceWorker registration failed: 
ServiceWorker script at https://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/...dd2e/service-worker.js 
              for scope https://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/...dd2e/ encountered an error during installation.
Empty String
```

When I upload the files to my own site, they run with no problem:

```
ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:  https://dev.example.com/thimble/
```

Is there some way I can encourage Mozilla Thimble to get the service-worker script to load? If so, it will considerably simplify the production process for my students.